# Как вернуть цвет Default

Tags: xcode, iphone

У меня цвет текста кнопки стоит по умолчанию - светло голубой.
В процессе его меняю на серый при нажатии:

```
[_rightStopButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

А вот при повторном нажатии он должен опять принимать цвет по умолчанию, а как это сделать?
`blueColor` не подходит, так как не такой как цвет по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cамый простой и правильный вариант при такой постановке задачи будет не менять цвет по нажатию, а менять свойство кнопки selected  и выставить для этих состояний (UIControlStateNormal и UIControlStateSelected) нужные вам цвета. Ну а при нажатии на кнопку написать `_rightStopButton.selected = !_rightStopButton.selected`

Также в принципе можно посмотреть какой конкретно цвет в RGB у вас по умолчанию с помощью инструмента DigitalColor Meter (он установлен в маках по дефолту, по крайней мере в 10,7 так было, про 10.8 и 10.9 точно сказать не могу - не помню запускал ли его), а дальше сгенерить его с помощью `[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255. green:green/255. blue:blue/255. alpha:1]`. Деление на 255. введено т,к. инструмент дает числа от 0 до 255 (хотя может там и есть какие настройки, уже не помню - давно не использовал), а метод использует от 0 до 1

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Сделал так:
[_rightStopButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(25/255.0) green:(120/255.0) blue:(250/255.0) alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];